# My mac use a link can download a file, but in a windows server it did not download, get 404

Tags: google-chrome, mac

This is the link:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gae1L/openstack-log-colorizer/master/openstack_log_colorizer

In my Mac, I copy it to the safari, it will download a file(openstack-log-colorizer).

But I use mac connected a Windows Server machine, in that chrome, copy the link to it, get 404 error:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typed the URL manually, didn't you?

The [actual file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gaelL/openstack-log-colorizer/master/openstack_log_colorizer) comes from GitHub user `gaelL` (g, a, e, lowercase L, uppercase L).

Your link contains the username `gae1L` (g, a, e, one, uppercase L).